# In SML, are product types and function types type constructors?

Tags: types, functional-programming, programming-languages, sml, ml

In Ullman's SML book:

> We can build new types from old types T1 and T2, as follows.
>
> 1. T1 * T2 is a "product" type, whose values are pairs. The first component of the pair is of type T1 and the second is of type T2.
> 2. T1 -> T2 is a "function" type, whose values are functions with domain type T1 and range type T2.
> 3. We may create new types by following a type such as T1 by certain identifiers that act as type constructors.
>
>    (a) The list type constructor. That is, for every type T1, there is
>      another type T1 list, whose values are lists all of whose elements are
>      of type T1.
>
>    (b) The option type constructor. For every type T1 there is a type T1
>      option whose values are NONE and SOME x where x is any value of type
>      T1.
>
>    (c) Additional type constructors ref, array, and vector.

I was wondering if * in product types and -> in function types are considered type constructors?

If no, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They're not, but this is mostly just for syntactic reasons:

- `*` and `->` are keywords rather than identifiers (setting aside the unrelated use of `*` as an identifier in e.g. `3 * 4 = 12`).
- We write `int * real` and `int -> real` rather than `(int, real) *` and `(int, real) ->`.
- A type constructor has a fixed number of parameters (for example, `list` always takes one parameter — we can't write `(int, real) list` — and `int` always takes none), but `int * real * char * string` is a 4-tuple. (In other words: `*` is "overloaded" for any *n*-tuple type with *n* ≥ 2. So it's like *infinitely many* type constructors, rather than just one.)

But I don't think there's any reason that it *must* be this way. One could imagine a parallel-universe version of Standard ML that:

- did not define `*` and `->` as reserved words, but just as identifiers in the initial basis (analogously to `ref` or `int`).
- allowed type constructors to be made infix  (analogously to how `3 + 4` means `op+ (3, 4)`), and declared `*` and `->` as such.
- didn't support the `*` notation for products of three or more types, but rather, interpreted `int * real * char * string` as `((int * real) * char) * string`. (In our universe, `'a * 'b * … * 'n` is just syntactic sugar for `{ 1: 'a, 2: 'b, …, 14: 'n }`; perhaps in the parallel universe that's not considered very useful for products of three or more types?)

In fact, even in our own universe, we can write:

```
type ('a, 'b) pair = 'a * 'b
type ('a, 'b, 'c) triple = 'a * 'b * 'c
type ('a, 'b) function = 'a -> 'b
```

which creates type constructors `pair`, `triple`, and `function` such that `(int, real) pair` is synonymous with `int * real`, `(int, real, char) triple` is synonymous with `int * real * char`, and `(int, real) function` is synonymous with `int -> real`. (Not that anyone *wants* that.)

Comment: Thanks. They are not type constructors, so what are they called? "type constructor keywords"?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not aware of a name for them as a group. The *Definition* definitely doesn't treat them as a group; it actually just defines `int * real * char` in an appendix, as syntactic sugar for `{ 1: int, 2: real, 3: char }`. I've never seen anyone else treat them as a group, either. They're just two different bits of syntax, with two different bits of associated semantics.